# Understanding mapreduce.framework.name wrt Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, mrv2

I am learning Hadoop and came to know that that there are two versions of the framework viz: Hadoop1 and Hadoop2.

If my understanding is correct, in Hadoop1, **the execution environment** is based on two daemons viz `TaskTracker` and `JobTracker` whereas in Hadoop2 (aka yarn), the execution environment is based on "new daemons" viz `ResourceManager`, `NodeManager`, `ApplicationMaster`.

Please correct me if this is not correct.

## I came to know of the following configuration parameter:

> mapreduce.framework.name
>   possible values which it can take: `local` , `classic` , `yarn`

I don't understand what does they actually mean; for example if I install Hadoop 2 , then how can it have old execution environment (which has `TaskTracker`, `JobTracker`).

Can anyone help me what these values mean?

Comment: Added some details around the query, hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `yarn` stands for MR version 2.
- `classic` is for MR version 1
- `local` for local runs of the MR jobs.

MR V1 and MR V2 are just about how resources are managed and a job is executed. The current hadoop release is capable of both (and even in local lightweight mode). When you set the value as `yarn`, you are simply instructing the framework to use `yarn` way to execute the job. Similarly when you set it to `local`, you just telling the framework that there is no cluster for execution and its all within a JVM. It is **not** a different infrastructure for MR V1 and MR V2 framework; its just the **way** of job execution, which changes.

`jobTracker`, `TaskTracker` etc are all just daemon thread, which are spawned when needed and killed.

MRv1 uses the `JobTracker` to create and assign tasks to data nodes. This was found to be too inefficient when dealing with large cluster, leading to `yarn`

MRv2 (aka `YARN`, "Yet Another Resource Negotiator") has a Resource Manager for each cluster, and each data node runs a Node Manager. For each job, one slave node will act as the `Application Master`, monitoring resources/tasks, etc.

Local mode is given to simulate and debug MR application within a single machine/JVM.

**EDIT: Based on comments**

`jps` (Java Virtual Machine Process Status)is a JVM tool, which according to [official page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html):

> The jps tool lists the instrumented HotSpot Java Virtual Machines
>   (JVMs) on the target system. The tool is limited to reporting
>   information on JVMs for which it has the **access permissions**.

So,

1. `jps` is *not* a big data tool, rather a java tool which tells about JVM, however it does not divulge any information on processes running within the JVM.
2. It only list the JVM, it has access to. It means there still be certain JVMs which remains undetected.

Keeping the above points in mind, if you observed that `jsp` command emits different result based on hadoop deployment mode:

1. Local (or Standalone) mode: There are no daemons and everything runs on a single JVM.
2. Pseudo-Distributed mode: Each daemon(Namenode, Datanode etc) runs on its own JVM on a single host.
3. Distributed mode: Each Daemon run on its own JVM across a cluster of hosts.

Hence each of the processes may or may not run in same JVM and hence `jps` output will be different.

Now in distributed mode, the MR v2 framework works in *default* mode. i.e. `yarn`; hence you see yarn specific daemons running

```
Namenode
Datanode
ResourceManager
NodeManager
```

Apache Hadoop 1.x (MRv1) consists of the following daemons:

```
Namenode
Datanode
Jobtracker
Tasktracker
```

Note that `NameNode` and `DataNode` are common between two, because they are `HDFS` specific daemon, while other two are `MR v1` and `yarn` specific.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got your point, but i can't still understand how we can "just" run in either YARN way (in which we have different daemons) or classic way (in which we have JT and TT); when we do jps we see NM, RM etc. I still have this doubt. Can you please help understand?